# Existence and nonexistence of periodic solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

This is related to the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059867/condition-for-the-existence-of-periodic-solutions/2059883#2059883) that I asked yesterday.

> Suppose the functions $a,f \in C(\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R})$ are both periodic with period $\omega.$ There are three parts for this question.

Show that $x'+a(t)x=f(t),$ has a unique $\omega$-periodic solution if and only if $\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\omega} a(t)~dt \neq 0}.$ (This is DONE !)

There's one more question regarding the same equation.
Show that, if $\int_{0}^{\omega}a(t)~dt=0,$ then the equation may have either no $\omega$-periodic solution or all of its solution are $\omega$-periodic. Also, under the same conditions, for which functions $f$ does the equation has $\omega$-periodic solutions ?

My approach: Let $A(\omega)=\int_{0}^{\omega}a(t)~dt.$ Suppose that $\int_{0}^{\omega}a(t)~dt=0.$ Then $e^{A(\omega)}=1,$ and thus we can't solve for $x(0),$ and hence there are no $\omega$-periodic solutions. I don't know how to the rest. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's wrong.

The general solution of this linear differential equation can be written $$x(s) = \exp(-A(s)) \left(x(0) + \int_0^s f(t) \exp(A(t))\; dt\right)$$
where $A(s) = \int_0^s a(t)\; dt$.  If $A(\omega) = 0$, that gives you
$x(\omega) = x(0) + \int_0^\omega f(t) \exp(A(t))\; dt$.
Whether this solution is periodic or not depends on $\int_0^\omega f(t) \exp(A(t))\; dt$.

Comment: "and thus we can't solve for $x(0)$, and hence there are no $\omega$-periodic solutions".

Comment: As I said, it depends on $\int_0^\omega f(t) \exp(A(t))\; dt$.  So: what does this have to be in order for $x(t)$ to be $\omega$-periodic?

Comment: No.  Put it another way: what is $x(\omega) - x(0)$?

Comment: ... and we're looking at the case $A(\omega) = 0$.  So what is $x(\omega) - x (0)$, and what does it need to be in order for the solution to be $\omega$-periodic?

Comment: Yes, we need $x(\omega) = x(0)$.  No, $f(t) \ne 0$.  $x(\omega) - x(0) = \int_0^\omega f(t) \exp(A(t))\; dt$.  **That** is what needs to be $0$.

Comment: The zero function is allowed, it's just not the only possibility.